# How to deal with ValueTask<T> in F#?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#, async-await, c#-to-f#

So apparently .NET's brand new `ValueTask<T>` is the *leaner* version of `Task<T>`. That's cool, but if before I had to use `Async.AwaitTask` to integrate my F# Async workflows with Task, what should I do with ValueTask now?

Comment: There is an RFC to add support for this to F# with an `AwaitValueTask` function.  https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/RFCs/FS-1021-value-task-interop.md

Comment: You can implement `Async.AwaitTask` quite easily in terms of the more primitive `Async.FromContinuations` - I imagine you could do the same for `ValueTask<'t>`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Before [`Async.AwaitValueTask`](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/RFCs/FS-1021-value-task-interop.md) is implemented (thanks Aaron), one can use ValueTask's [AsTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask.astask?view=netcore-2.1) method, and use `Async.AwaitTask` for now, as the simplest solution.

Answer (score 5):

My OSS project ["FusionTasks"](https://github.com/kekyo/FSharp.Control.FusionTasks) can handle naturally and implicitly interprets both `Task` and `ValueTask` same as F# `Async` type on F# async workflow:

```ml
let asyncTest = async {
  use ms = new MemoryStream()

  // FusionTasks directly interpreted Task class in F# async-workflow block.
  do! ms.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length)
  do ms.Position <- 0L

  // FusionTasks directly interpreted Task<T> class in F# async-workflow block.
  let! length = ms.ReadAsync(data2, 0, data2.Length)
  do length |> should equal data2.Length
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With the new task expressions, it is explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/task-expressions#value-tasks

I just implemented a `System.IAsyncDisposable` which returns a `System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask` like so:

```ml
    interface IAsyncDisposable with
        member _.DisposeAsync(): ValueTask = 
            task {
                use _ = client
                return ()
            } |> ValueTask
```

You can see that I'm just piping the task to `ValueTask`.